# RegEx and Django URL expressions

Tags: regex, django

Shouldn't this accept two different patterns, such as `/hello/` and `/hello/123/`? The first seems to be a catch-all.

```
(r'^(?P<org>\S+)/$', 'path.to.view'),
(r'^(?P<org>\S+)/(?P<id>\d{3})/$', 'path.to.view'),
```

What I really want to find is a slug and a number of varying length (though above it shows only three characters): `/hello-slug-name/123/` or just `/hello-slug-name/`

Edit:

A note for posterity's sake: of the two answers below, both are very helpful in for understanding what's going on here. I'm making the answer that I ultimately used in my implementation as "correct" with the green tick, but both are very insightful and helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this:

```
(r'^(?P<org>[-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$', 'path.to.view'),
(r'^(?P<org>[-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'path.to.view'),
```

Answer (score 3):

The first regex matches any string that consists of non-whitespace characters and ends in a slash. Therefore it matches both your strings.

The second regex matches a string that consists of non-whitespace characters, followed by a slash, followed by three digits, followed by another slash.

From your example I gather that by "number of varying length" you also mean "possibly zero (in which case the slash is also dropped)". One regex that would cover all these cases would be

```
^(?P<org>\S+?)/(?:(?P<id>\d+)/)?$
```

Comment: I only broke it up so that I could write two separate views to handle each type of request :)